# php populate text box values with loop in a loop

Tags: php

Im running two loops for loops for creating textbox for a count 100 for each loop

I inserted the values in the table i want to populate the text boxes from table as array the

array is given below..

for  each master_id in $arr1 there are 3 values in $arr2   .

My question is how to  populate text box values with  loop in a loop

```
<?

while($room_more = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry1))
    {
            $name_arr[] = $room_more;

            //print_r($room_more);
            $id_qry = mysql_query($qry2);
            while($id_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($id_qry))
            {
                $id_array[] = $id_row;

            }

    }   
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)

            {
            ?>
            <table  width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="rownumber_<? echo $i;?>" "style=display: none;" >
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="<? echo $room_more_arr[$i-1]['name'];?>" id="name_<? echo $i;?>_0"  ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <?
  for($j=1;$j<=100;$j++)

 {
 ?><tr><table id="rownumber_<? echo $i;?>_<? echo $j;?>"  width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
     <td  width="17%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="11%"><input type="text" name="id[<? echo $i;?>][<? echo $j;?>]" value="" id="id_<? echo $i;?>_<? echo $j;?>" size="4" ></td>
    </tr></table></tr>
            <? } } ?>

?>
```

My array is like this

```
$arr1 =  Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [master_id] => 4
            [avroom_id] => 2
            [name] => name1

        )

    [1] => Array(
            [master_id] => 5
            [avroom_id] => 2
            [name] => name2

        )
 );
$arr2  = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [master_id] => 4
            [id] => id1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [master_id] => 4
            [id] => id2

        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [master_id] => 4
            [id] => id3

        )

    [3] => Array
        (

            [master_id] => 5
            [id] => id4

        )

)
```

Comment: so what is your expected output

Comment: for  each master_id in $arr1 there are 3 values in $arr2   .I want to populate  the id1,id2,id3,.. etc corresponding to the key =>value master_id

Comment: I was able to explain it clear ?

Comment: so you need to loop for $arr1 and if $arr1 'master_id' = $arr2 master_id then make an input type text?